# Why GLKit scaling is causing color/lighting to darken?

Tags: ios4, opengl-es, glkit

Im seeing a strange behavior that i cant seem to grasp.
For some reason when I apply a scale (on the z axis), my texture mapped polygon mesh becomes darkened, as if lighting is suddenly disabled or the diffuse color being set to 0. If i reverse the scale (so that scaling goes back to 0) then the color becomes bright and vibrant in color again.

*** Update with additional info. ***
The brightness seems fine when the z values on my vertices are at their original/initialized values. But when i scale along the z axis, this is when the color goes dim (not completely dark, but a noticeable change in brightness). 
I am using an index buffer to render.

What on earth could cause this "glitch" ?

The code related to this is here:

```
float aspect = fabsf(self.view.bounds.size.width / self.view.bounds.size.height);
GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(60.0f), aspect, 0.1f, 100.0f);

self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix = projectionMatrix;

// Compute the model view matrix for the object rendered with GLKit
GLKMatrix4 modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0f, 15.0f, -90.0f);
modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(modelViewMatrix, rotationAngle, 0, 1, 0);

// where g_depthScale is a value that increases based on a slider control.
modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Scale(modelViewMatrix, 0.1f, 0.1f, g_depthScale);

self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = modelViewMatrix;
```

Comment: Most common mistake to produce this is when you use scale you also scale normals. Do normalize the normals so they always have the length of 1.

Comment: @Matic. Convert this comment into an Answer and the reward goes to you.

Comment: ok. i enabled glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE) on initialization time. Now the entire texture is totally black. This is totally unexpected!

Comment: maybe the glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE) is not working because im using the GLKitBaseEffect (which i think is a basic out-of-box way of doing pixel shaders). If this is the case, i believe the normalize via OpenGL does not work.

Comment: You know, you could simply normalize the normal in any of the shaders since you seem to be using them. Just do note at this point that you need to normalize the 3d vector, not the 4d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Matic Oblak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/526828/matic-oblak) says, you might be scaling the normals as you scale the model.

A cheap and easy way of getting a whole scene to scale is to change the view angle of projection matrix, see [OpenGL ES 2.0 Pinch and Zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115787/opengl-es-2-0-pinch-and-zoom/16123403#16123403)

Comment: Ok. If this is true (i have yet to verify what my normals are... which im not even sure how to do after having them initialized) then this has got to be the silliest bug. I mean, this IS a bug, right?